# Islands of land locked by mountains

Tags: climate, geography

So, for this story I'm drafting, I want to use this type of landscape for the main region where the plot develops.

Basically, instead of a sea of water proper, the islands are low valleys amidst steep mountains.

My question is, is this a possible structure in the real world? And what would be the consequences on the climate of the areas?

Edit:
It was two part but I decided only to ask about part of the problem. Correcting it now.
The Isles, the name of the place, is supposed to an archipelago. The terrain of these Islands are fertile valleys surrounded by steep mountain.

Basically, the Islands are made of a series of low mountains surrounded by higher ones, themselves surronded by smaller ones lower than sea level. All forming a single are called the Maw.

Comment: Is there no water at all?

Comment: I don't get it. How is this supposedly fictional world different from, for example, Switzerland? You know, a small country in Western Europe, consisting of many fertile valleys separated by steep mountains, basically impossible for an army to conquer, sufficiently isolated between them that four different languages are spoken...

Comment: @AlexP Believe it or not, I was thinking of Autria... My father from Italy lives there with his second wife.:) Its an inverse island world, so to speak. I wouldnt say Zwitserland is impossible to conquer though. Four different languages? You mean retro roman as fourth language?

Comment: @AlexP you could answer with that.

Comment: This srtucture is used by Asimov to evade the difficulties of an eyeball planet.

Comment: Whats the use of the landscape?

Comment: The landscape you envision would come in very handy for a region where a storm is raging at the surface. The deep islands would be islands of windstillity. You could connect the islands with tunnels. This structure was in fact used by Asimov to escape the effects of an eyeball planet. On the sides of the planet (the region between lihjt and dark) there are huges storms blowing from the light side to the dark side. In the deep valleys there is almost no wind, as you can imagine.

Comment: What did your research tell you about whether or not valleys exist among mountains?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: It's *Rhaeto*-Romance, not \*\*Retroroman. The region where the language is spoken was called Rhaetia in the Antiquity. (The speakers of the language call it simply Rumantsch.) (I just looked in Wikipedia and it seems that nowadays the preferred English name of the language is Romansh. But then it's Wikipedia, which sometimes takes a rather strange position on matters linguistic.) (Of course it's not *impossible* to conquer; but it is very very difficult...)

Comment: @AlexP Next time Im in Zwitserland I wont make that mistake again. Maybe I can better speak German or Italian. Though I dont know if they all speak four languages. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: No, they don't all speak four languages. Everybody speaks their own language, plus of course the standard form of that language (so that us foreigners can understand them -- to my Romanian ears, native Swiss Italian and Swiss German are barely recognizable as Italian or German.) And everybody in the German-speaking area seems to be able to speak English.

Comment: Thanks, Lawrence! I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @AlexP: Actually many Swiss do speak at least 3 of the 4, plus English.  When I lived there, I was amazed by people like my bank clerk, who could effortlessly switch between conversations in multiple languages.

Comment: The problem with having fertile valleys below sea level is that unless the valley is in a desert (e.g. Death Valley in the US, the Dead Sea valley in the Middle East), rainfall will soon fill it with water, and you will have a lake.  But in general the terrain is possible, but you need either some desert (so you can have endorheic basins: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorheic_basin ), or some rivers flowing out of the area.

Answer (score 5):

[Tibet](http://www.raize.ch/Reisen/velo-eurasien/satellite-images.htm) (in the picture), Austria, Switzerland, Nepal, are just some examples of countries with this very morphology.

Mountains, mountains everywhere, as long as the eye can see, with valleys used for human settlement.

[image]

As you can imagine the climate will be pretty cold, with short summers and usually regular precipitations, in form of snow or rain, according to the season.

Comment: At least in Switzerland, most of the population lives in the Central Plateau, a land of rolling hills and mild weather.